# Rollup + Typescript output JS file per component

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I'm creating a reusable component library with React, TypeScript and Rollup.

Bundling this library into a single output file `index.js` works great. But, there are no `.js` output files generated for my **individual components**.

However, I'm trying to ensure I can use specific imports in my TypeScript projects.

E.g: `import { ComponentA } from "my-components/lib/ComponentA`;

This would then ensure my other components are not included when bundling my project afterwards.

**So my question is:** how can I configure Rollup so that all components are output as well into separate component output files?

My file structure looks like:

```
src
│ index.ts
└─components
  │ index.ts
  ├─ComponentA
  │   index.ts
  │   ComponentA.tsx
  └─ComponentB
      index.ts
      ComponentB.tsx
```

My rollup config is:

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
      exports: "named",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "es",
      exports: "named",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    resolve({
      browser: true
    }),
    typescript({
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
      exclude: "**/__tests__/**",
      clean: true
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: ["node_modules/**"],
      exclude: ["**/*.stories.js"],
      namedExports: {
        "node_modules/react/react.js": [
          "Children",
          "Component",
          "PropTypes",
          "createElement"
        ],
        "node_modules/react-dom/index.js": ["render"]
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Which outputs to:

```
lib
│ index.d.ts
│ index.es.js
│ index.es.js.map
│ index.js
│ index.js.map
└─components
  │ index.d.ts
  ├─ComponentA
  │   index.d.ts
  │   ComponentA.d.ts
  └─ComponentB
      index.d.ts
      ComponentB.d.ts
```

**What I want to achieve** is that in the *output* (lib) folder there are for example also `ComponentA.js` and `ComponentB.js` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding flag `preserveModule`

```js
export default {
  ...
  preserveModules: true,
  ...
}
```

It should work, a demonstration repo for this: https://github.com/daleyjem/rollup-preserve-modules

Comment: `preserveModules` is deprecated

Comment: can I have a reference?

Comment: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#deprecated-options see the third option in the list

`Use the output.preserveModules output option instead, which has the same signature.`